# Transition matrix inequality with transient state

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $S$ be a finite Markov chain and $j$ a transient state. The problem I am working on is to show that for all $i \in S$, $$\sum_{n \geq 0}P^{n}(i, j) \leq \sum_{n \geq 0}P^{n}(j, j)$$ where $P$ denotes the transition matrix.

Since $j$ is transient, then this is the same as showing that $$\rho_{ij} \leq \rho_{jj}$$ where $\rho_{ij} = P(T_{j} < \infty | X_{0} = i)$ and $T_{j} = \min\{n \geq 1 : X_n = j\}$ is the first time of return to $j$. We also have $\rho_{jj}$ similarly defined.

Therefore I need to show that $$P(T_{j} < \infty | X_0 = i) \leq P(T_{j} < \infty | X_0 = j)$$ for all states $i \in S$. Why is this true? Why am I more likely to return to $j$ if I start out at $j$?

Answer (score 0):

I did it but instead of i and j I used x and y...
We know that
    $$P^0(x,y)=P[X_0=y|X_0=x]=\begin{cases}
         1 & if x=y\\
         0 & if x \neq y 
         \end{cases}$$
In other hand , let's see that
    \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(y,y)&=P^0(y,y)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(y,y)\\
  &=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(y,y)\\
  &=1+\frac{\rho_{yy}}{1-\rho_{yy}} \tag{Hint}\\
  &=\frac{1}{1-\rho_{yy}}.
 \end{align*}

Therefore, 
    \begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(x,y)&=P^0(x,y)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(x,y)\\
  &=0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(x,y)\\
  &=\frac{\rho_{xy}}{1-\rho_{yy}} \tag{Hint}\\
  &\leq \frac{1}{1-\rho_{yy}}. \tag{$0 \leq \rho_{xy} \leq 1$}\\
  &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(y,y).
 \end{align*}

Hence, 
    $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(x,y) \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P^n(y,y).$$
Q.E.D.